How to attach ~1mm fiber optic cable to wall
I have fiber optic cable (white plastic, about 1mm in diameter) running into my unit, installed by the provider. This terminated in a reel of cable (about an extra 30m). I decided to move the ONT, which is working fine, but I am not sure of the best way to stick the cable to the wall. I have looked at the bit installed by the provider, but I cannot tell how it was done. Is it painted in? Glued? Tape? I imagine there must be a standard way of doing this.


The must important thing to know: fiber optic cable has a minimum bend radius; trying to turn  a corner more sharply loses light and may even break the fiber. Exactly what but at radius is depends on exactly how that cable is made, but  it's usually at least an inch, sometimes several inches. Be careful handling and routing it.

Check with your service provider on moving the ONT. Moving it yourself may be a violation of their service rules. They may move it for you, maybe for free, so the fiber stays in proper order. Another thought, they may make you pay for fixing the fiber if you break it, even if you are allowed to move the ONT yourself.

My fiber comes to the exterior ONT, so there's no need to cover or move anything.  Never seen an interior install like that.  (Looks like interior, anyway).

I've seen it done with hot-melt glue.

When my provider installed my fiber optic cable, they simply ran a small bead of clear silicone caulk along the route and then pressed the cable into the caulk bead. They had rounded  inside corners and avoided outside corners because the cable could not be bent that sharp.
